# My inputs for the foreign key are not working and im not sure

Tags: sql, oracle

I was not sure if the multiple column for distance foreign key was correct.

Here is my code:

```
    DROP TABLE Trips;
    DROP SEQUENCE Trips_seq;

    CREATE TABLE Trips( 
    Trips_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,  
    Date_of_Trip DATE NOT NULL, 
    Payment NUMBER NOT NULL,
    Destination_Town VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, 
    Source_Town VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL,
    Customer_ID NUMBER NOT NULL

   CONSTRAINT Trip_pk
     PRIMARY KEY (Trips_ID, Trips_seq),
   CONSTRAINT Customer_fk
     FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID) REFERENCES Customer (Customer_ID),
   CONSTRAINT Owner_fk
     FOREIGN KEY (Owner_ID) REFERENCES Vehicle_Owners (Owner_ID),
   CONSTRAINT Payment_fk
     FOREIGN KEY (Payment_ID) REFERENCES Payment (Payment_ID),
   CONSTRAINT Distances_fk
     FOREIGN KEY (Destination_Town, Source_Town) REFERENCES 
   Distances (Destination_Town, Source_Town)s
```

);
CREATE SEQUENCE Trips_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

Comment: We're going to need more info mate. Have you tried to run this? What results/errors do you get? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: @L.Newell It says its missing a right parenthesis. sorry

Comment: You have multiple other errors, mainly using columns that do not exist: Owner_id, Payment_id, Trips_seq.  You create a `trips_seq` but that does not make it a column in the table, so part of your PK is missing. Owner_id, Payment_id have a similar problem, since they do not exist they cannot be a FK.  You need a comma after the `not null` on customer_id and `constraint`. You have finished defining the columns but are still defining the table.  Finally after adding the closing  right parenthesis the `s` will generate a syntax error. It should be a semi-colon closing the statement.

Answer (score 0):

I count 12 left parenthesis and 11 right parenthesis in your code. It looks like you need to add a right parenthesis before your 's' e.g.:

```
Distances (Destination_Town, Source_Town)) s
```